# magento import not working for products set with visibility of 1 (not visible individually)

Tags: import, configurable-product, csv

I have a spreadsheet which I use to import my simple products. Originally, I only had products on there which had their visibility set to 1 (not visible individually) - as they were meant to be associative products for my configurables - and they uploaded perfectly.

Recently, however, I have added on products with visibility set to 4 and the import - though showing no errors - only seems to import those products which are set to 4 and not those set to 1!

Moreover, the same spreadsheet doesn't seem to work anymore even when it contains only products set to 1 as it had before. The import shows no errors but the products do not upload at all (not on the frontend and not on the backend).

The products set to 4 and set to 1 are otherwise identical.

Answer (score 1):

after hours of frustration I realized that these items (the ones with visibility set to 1) had descriptions that ended in

> "..." (three periods - I actually wrote "loading...").

Apparently these three dots were screwing up the CSV (or the way Magento reads the CSV). Remove the three dots and everything works!!!

I am writing this here on the off chance that someone else encounters this same issue.

Comment: I think I read exactly thos provlem some tome ago on stackoverflow.com